# In my Layout Editor, [delete constraint] [baseline edit] and [cycle chain mode] buttons A.K.A. (x, ab and chainbuttons) are not visible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I can't see the [baseline edit] [delete constraint] and [cycle chain mode] buttons (x, ab and chainbuttons) below the selected components in the Layout Editor in my updated Android Studio 3.4.1 Is there a way to activate them?

[I can't see the icons under the buttons in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsi3M.png)

Comment: edit the layouts in raw xml bro, like a real programmer :D

Comment: @Vucko I don't agree with you on this subject. Even in the official [constraint-layout documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) they give the examples using the layout editor. Using ConstraintLayout from the layout editor saves A-LOT  of development time. It's true that you need to know your way through the XML but for 99% of the times, you can manage to build your  layout without using the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently they moved those options to the right-click menu. When you right-click one of the chained element [you can see the chain mode option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGZdc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think @EnsLab answer will do, but I want to add another option.

you can also:

1. Go to the attributes inspector and click the search button.
2. Search for "chain"
3. If not already expanded, expand the layout constraints list.
4. In here you'll find the "layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle" and the "layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle"
5. Clicking on the dropdown button will show you the cycle chain modes that you can use/select.